# Youtube Iframe Player API Developer Policy Inquiries

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I would like to ask about developer policies of Youtube Iframe Player API(https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Our team is currently developing an iOS app including Youtube embedded player.

We would like to check if our use cases below violate the rules for embedded youtube player.

1. Would it be okay if we use invisible player which we set opacity zero for purpose of getting thumbnail images in video?

- Thumnails are taken by invisible player in the way as seeking to specific time and capture view at the time.
- The thumnails are solely used for progress bar which consist of sequential images as green box in the below image and each image indicates each parts of video and there is no other purposes.
- Images are made and used only in client local environment and not saved in our database.
- Additionaly, can we provide the thumbnail extracted in the above method which background is removed?

2. Would it be possible that we hide below title bar which shows when player paused by adjusting CSS style, view frame size ?

- Is there the other way to hide title bar ?
  it seems that there are other mobile app services in Korea also using embeded player without titlebar like ‘Cake’ ( [https://apps.apple.com/kr/app/cake-케이크-영어회화/id1350420987](https://apps.apple.com/kr/app/cake-%EC%BC%80%EC%9D%B4%ED%81%AC-%EC%98%81%EC%96%B4%ED%9A%8C%ED%99%94/id1350420987) )

3. We are developing feature ‘Metronome’ using BPM(beat per minute). for this, we need to use Audio PCM data in Video. regarding this we are currently examining three cases.

- is it allowed to extract audio file from video to get PCM data?
- is it allowed to access to device’s audio buffer to get PCM data?
- is it allowed to record audio with mobile device to make audio file ?

4. Is it possible to provide a Metronome function that repeatedly plays a specific sound simultaneously with the audio of the Youtube video?
5. Would it be okay if we invert embeded player left and right? we plan to provide a mirror mode for user so that they practice dance conveniently.
6. Is it possible to provide a function that play repeatedly the specific time range (ex. from 00:05 to 00:10)?
7. Is it possible to provide a function that does not play immediately when the play button is pressed, but counts down for a certain period of time, such as 3 seconds, to play?

Comment: As far as I know you won't get any legal advice on StackOverflow, you should ask YouTube directly but I bet that they won't answer you.. Good luck with that anyway.

Comment: Thank you i've already ask same thing to Youtube as well, not sure that was right contact point though.. hopefully they answer... 
if there is anyone who know contact point about this concern please let me know thank you